# Looking for command line query for check if there is Checksum error in Wireshark file

Tags: wireshark

i looking for command for check if my Wireshark file has Checksum error, i can do it with the command **ip.checksum_bad == 1** but this is from the application GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tshark -R 'ip.checksum_bad==1' -Vr file
```

will do the trick ...

See the man page for tshark.

Comment: and there is command to fix those packets in case ob bad checksum ?

Comment: Huh ? Wireshark *dissects* data for display to the user. So: the answer is no.